# How do I call third party APIs from with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

This may be a silly question,
I have an api which is used to validate data and do some custom stuff

Is possible to call this api from validate rule in firebase

```
 {
   "rules": {
      ".read": "true",
     //is it possible to do like this
      ".validate": "ajaxCall(Url/to/api/returns/bool)"
    }
 }
```

or what will be the best suited way to do third party api integration with firebase

I am using angularJs, bootstrap, firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have access to predefined server variables that Firebase provides you. Here is [a list from the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-predefined).

If you want to integrate with a third party API, you will need to run a server.

For realtime streaming you can either use the [`node.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) client or JVM client. If you chose the JVM client, you can host it on AppEngine (which is really easy to maintain). [This tutorial is really, really good](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio).

If you chose the `node.js` client you could do something like the following.

```
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>/purchases/user_1');
// Create a listener for every time something is added
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {

  // When something is added, make the ajax call
  ajaxCall('url/to/api/returns/bool', function(error, data) {
     // take action from 3rd party API here
  });

});
```

Comment: My requirement was, I have to save some of the data to different database, and this should happen directly between firebase and my server.                so I have to do it on angular side!!

Comment: I feel your pain and 100% agree. The problem is creating a secure connection to your 3rd party database requires a server. If it wasn't a on a server everybody/anybody could gain access which would be super bad.

Comment: My aim was to remove api layer. but for doing custom stuff on data I must have to introduce api layer and call it from angular side.     Thanks for the answer.